# Junit time difference Gradle vs IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I'm trying to solve a weird behaviour:

when running tests from gradle (v3.4.1.): it takes 6 min (reported in console)
but the test report only reports ~3min 40s

when running the same tests, with the junit runner from IDEA, it takes ~1min30s.
I have no idea from where these differences. Ideally i would like to run gradle tests (on jenkins) as fast as in IDEA

(the configuration step only takes 11s, so thats not it)

I'm seeing alot of Gradle Test Executor, 149, looks like one per class - not sure if relevant to anything.

```
15:01:23.138 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Starting Gradle Test Executor 32.
15:01:23.170 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Initialized native services in: C:\Users\user\.gradle\native
15:01:23.170 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker] Gradle Test Executor 32 started executing tests.
15:01:23.269 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 32 STARTED
15:01:23.285 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor] Executing test class com.MyTest
15:01:23.285 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.MyTest STARTED
15:01:23.602 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 32 PASSED
15:01:23.602 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker] Gradle Test Executor 32 finished executing tests.
15:01:23.604 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Completed Gradle Test Executor 32.
15:01:23.643 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
15:01:23.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Test Executor 32' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
15:01:23.645 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.55.85 completed (1 in use)
15:01:23.645 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.55.86 started (1 in use).
15:01:23.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [b10e1e1c-468c-4f31-9409-42bb9cc0ee93 port:52755, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
15:01:23.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder] Creating Gradle Test Executor 33
```

Comment: For the record: you are sure that your gradle setup doesn't include a full build first? Or something like that: you are 100% positive that you are not comparing apple and oranges here?

Comment: I am running :myModule:test at the end it gets reported 6min
and then going into the test reports where test is reported at ~3min
I think I am comparing apples with apples

Comment: also running with --profile, the profile result reports that myModule:test took 6m35, but still the test report reports 3m. so wtf..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that a gradle plugin was configuring the project with

```
test {
  forkEvery = 1
}
```

Which explains why I had so many Gradle Test Executors.
I put it back to the default value of 0, and test time improved a lot.